# HTML5 Offline web apps NOT working in Android 2.x, iPhone. (However works in Android 4.0)

Tags: android, iphone, django, html, html5-appcache

Trying to implement offline feature of HTML5. After doing a lot of googling, this is how my code looks. (It's a django project; deployed in apache2.2 with `mod_wsgi` plugin)
**HTML**
`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html manifest="{{MEDIA_URL}}cache.manifest">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">      
          <title>MyHomeStuff</title>      
          <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}MyHomeStuff.js" ></script>
          <script></script>
       </head>
       <body>
         .............
       </body>
    </html>
```

`

**Apache conf\mime.types**
`text/cache-manifest manifest`

**\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py**
Added `'.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',` into `types_map` dict

(With the above addition to mimetypes.py, it started working for android 4.0)

**cache.manifest**
`CACHE MANIFEST`

`CACHE:`
`index.html`
`MyHomeStuff.js`

*EDIT:*
**views.py**
`

```
def offlineApp(request):
    t = get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'MEDIA_URL':'http://myDomain.com/site_media/'}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

*EDIT2*
**Is it required to use any specific `module/middleware` to handle `text/manifest` in `django` ?**

The app works as expected for chrome, opera and other desktop browsers; but doesn't load when in airplane mode for android 2.x, iPhone browsers. However it works with Android 4.0 browser!
What could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: OK! So I got some **workaround** for this. I used [manifesto](https://github.com/cyberdelia/manifesto) to implement offline apps in django. However I'm still looking out for any simple solution that uses just django (i.e., no additional packages like manifesto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from google groups [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/JuW3rWcBzcY/7LEEcYe2_bEJ)..

Essentially it tells this:

> when you're serving offline HTML5, you need to serve (at least) 2 pages -- a page with html, and a *completely separate* second page containing the manifest. The manifest file has a content type of text/cache-manifest; your HTML is served with a normal text/html content type.